# Replace normal block with same block that has a special property

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to use a command block that detects if there is a gold block in the player's inventory and replace it with a gold block that can only be placed on grass.

[image: How it looks]

Now, here is what I'm doing: I started a redstone clock which connects to a command block which has this command to clear all gold blocks.

```
clear @p gold_block
```

Then I have a comparator that takes that signal and points into another command block that gives the player a gold block that can only be placed on grass.

```
give @p gold_block 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:[grass]}
```

What happens is that this special gold block also gets removed by the previous command block. I've tried to give the gold block a name with the display tag, but I don't know how to configure the command to give the block both tags (Display & Can PlaceOn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give to the first gold block a name:

```
/give @p gold_block 1 0 {display:{Name:"a name"}}
```

And then run the `/clear` command like this:

```
/clear @p gold_block 0 1 {display:{Name:"a name"}}
```

This command will clear only the golden block that has the name "a name".

Now give your SPECIAL BLOCK, but with another name:

```
/give @p gold_block 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:[grass],display:{Name:"SPECIAL BLOCK"}}
```

You need to put another name that the clear command block doesn't affect.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!
But now, I'm running into another problem. When i place down the special gold block with the special property and then I try to break it again with a goldblock breaking pickaxe i gave myself but it just turns into a normal gold block again! Do you have any idea how to prevent this or is it just like that forever?

Comment: I don't think if it's possible. Unfortunately , the entity item form cannot be renamed , like an inventory item can be. Anyway I am sure this problem has a solution :D

Comment: Here is even more  detail to my contraption:
I want to place down gold blocks on a spot which if broken with a special pickaxe they get cleared and replaced on your inventory with the same gold block with the special property (CanPlaceOn)